# Get attributes of the first object in angular async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I am using rxjs and angular 6 and I have the following simple html to render a bunch of data via the async pipe

```
          <div *ngIf='results | async ; let items '>                                                
            <div *ngFor='let item of items'>
              <div>                    
                {{item.name}} already exists
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>
```

Now, I dont want to render all of them, just the first one, so I try to do something like

```
          <div *ngIf='results | async ; let items '>                                                
            <div *ngIf='items.length>0'>
              <div>                    
                {{items[0].name}}  already exists
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>
```

`items[0]` gives no errors and `items[0].name` works but I get `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` in the console.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: please check with adding this -> items[0]?.name

Comment: what do you see in the template if you add `{{ items[0] | json }}`?

Comment: You can use observable.pipe(take(1)); in your component and then proceed like you did in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf='results | async ; let items;'>                                                
  <div>{{items[0]?.name}}  already exists</div> 
</div>
```